# 3G Dongle Setup

Tags: raspbian

So I've been struggling to setup my 3G dongle (Wind Mobile) on my raspberry pi (running Raspbian).

I've installed `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` since that seems to be the common solution, but when running the Mobile Broadband wizard to setup a new device, my stick isn't listed. It just says "Any Device" and it's grayed out.

I've already installed `usb-modeswitch` as well and my device is listed (using `lsusb`) as:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA Modem)
```

It seems I'm almost there, except I'm such a n00b so I don't know how to connect to this thing.

**EDIT:** After setting up sakis3g (suggested by Alessandro), I'm able to select the right device but I can't seem to be able to connect.

APN values for Wind Mobile Internet seem to be either `internet.windmobile.ca` or `broadband.windmobile.ca`, yet neither of those work so I'm using `internet` instead since that was suggested by the modem itself.

From what I can gather APN_USER and APN_PASS should both be `Not Set`. I've tried making them blank as well as the string "Not Set" but sakis3g doesn't seem to allow blank usernames or passwords.

**EDIT2:**

I ended up using "user" and "pass" since I found an old forum post half-mentioning that APNs which don't require username/passwords can just be set as whatever.

Not sure why but it works when I disabled my xserver and did it by command line, setting each variable by hand in `/etc/sakis3g.conf`. The APN turned out to be `internet.windmobile.ca` after all.

Comment: The information in the first "Edit" includes an APN of "internet.windmobile,.ca " and I believe the comma is not likely to be correct. APNs that have the look of a domain would not have a comma. The APN in the second "Edit" looks correct, so I wonder if you were sidetracked by a simple typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable `network-manager` and use only `sakis3g`. It is a shell script that autoconfigures almost everything of your 3G connection, it also does the modeswitch if required by your hardware.
Unfortunately [the official site seems offline](http://www.sakis3g.org/), but you can [grab a copy from LinuxMind](http://www.linuxmind-italia.org/index.php?topic=17178.msg195052#msg195052) or just google for it.
Just download it, run it and you're done.

```
gunzip sakis3g.gz
chmod +x sakis3g
./sakis3g
```

Then I suggest a powered USB Hub to feed the dongle, the Raspberry USB port cannot output the required current. Everything will work, but in some hours you will probably encounter data corruption on the SD or a kernel panic.

Comment: So I've got `sakis3g` setup, the only APN that works is "internet" (suggested by the modem when running `sakis3g`). I can't seem to find the right username and password though.

Comment: You can find APN, username and password on your provider website or in your mobile contract. Or ask the call center. Google for "Wind mobile $yourcountry apn settings". Even if such informations are public sakis3g database is not complete.

Comment: @dudeofea try these ones http://www2.windmobile.ca/media/pdfs/Non-WIND/Non-WIND_Device_Configuration.pdf - http://forum.melbia.com/wind-mobile/wind-mobile-internet-settings-for-nokia-android-canada-t471.html -   http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1691746-Wind-Internet-Settings